# PowerShell replace multiple elements in text file depending on the contents

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Thanks in advance for your time.

I'm new-ish to PowerShell, trying to write a script which can search through a bunch of text files and pick out certain elements, then use those to replace other elements. Here is an example of the content:

```
OrderLine="0002" <Image>11770060002_outside.jpg</Image><Image>11770060002_inside.jpg</Image>
OrderLine="0003" <Image>11770060003_outside.jpg</Image><Image>11770060003_inside.jpg</Image>
```

So what I want to do is step through, pick out the 'OrderLine' value and put it into a variable, then replace the 'Image' value - it's probably easier to just show the intended output than try to explain it!

```
OrderLine="0002" <Image>11770060002.pdf</Image>
OrderLine="0003" <Image>11770060003.pdf</Image>
```

As you can see, the filename has been replaced and the ending of the name is the same as the OrderLine. There could be only one order line in the file, or there could be 150 but the rule will always be the same.

I know it looks like XML, but it isn't valid (don't ask) so it won't parse as such, needs to be a text based solution.

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Edit: Here's what I have so far, this works BUT it takes the value from the filename (which is the same as the first entry in the file i.e. 0001) so it only works for files with a single order. I need to update the routine to cope with multiple OrderLine entries as above.

```
$File_Folder = "C:\PSTEST\TEST\"
$Output_Folder = "C:\PSTEST\TEST\OUTPUT\"

$array = Get-ChildItem $File_Folder\*.xml

foreach($item in $array){

$xml_filename = $item.FullName.substring($File_Folder.Length)

$just_filename = $xml_filename -replace ".xml", ""
$just_filename = $just_filename -replace "Order_PO", ""

$replace_outside_original = '<image>' + $just_filename + '_outside.jpg</Image>'
$replace_outside_with = '<image>' + $just_filename + '.pdf</image>'

$replace_inside_original = '<image>' + $just_filename + '_inside.jpg</Image>'
$replace_inside_with = ''

$destination_file = $Output_Folder + 'Order_PO' + $just_filename + '.xml'

(Get-Content $File_Folder\$xml_filename) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace $replace_outside_original, $replace_outside_with `
       -replace $replace_inside_original, $replace_inside_with `
    } | Set-Content $destination_file
}
```

Comment: Do the last digits of the jpg filename always match the OrderLine? From the example, it appears to be simply a matter of replacing '_outside.jpg' with '.pdf', and then trimming off the last Image element.

Comment: Yes - I can do that singularly with substring and I can create a 'to replace' variable and replace it with a blank string, but the problem is really that I can't work out how to read in the OrderLine value, and then the second problem is how to keep going through until I've got each entry.

Comment: Ah, @mjolinor I see what you mean, sorry - yes, you're correct - in theory I could just replace all instances of _outside.jpg with .pdf but then I can't think of a way to say 'and take off the second image element' programatically because the tags are the same for the first and the second so a simple replace won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

Starting with one of the lines you need to match:

OrderLine="0002" 11770060002_outside.jpg11770060002_inside.jpg

Replace the variable parts  with regex metacharacters. In this case the variable data is the digits:

```
$regex  = 'OrderLine="\d+" <Image>\d+_outside.jpg</Image><Image>\d+_inside.jpg</Image>'
```

Then add grouping parens for the part(s) you want to keep:

```
$regex  = '(OrderLine="\d+" <Image>\d+_outside.jpg</Image>)<Image>\d+_inside.jpg</Image>'
```

Then use -match to filter out the lines the that match the regex, a -replace with a backreference to the capture group to do the trim, and another replace to replace the literal parts of the text, then outupt the result to another file.

```
(get-content file.txt) -match $regex -replace $regex,'$1' -replace '_outside\.jpg','.pdf' |
 set-content newfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @mjolinor - appreciate the help! I'm still struggling to put it into a loop which will step through the OrderLine values until it's done all of them, but I'll keep working on it - I'm probably missing something obvious as my brain is fried from looking at this for days!

Comment: You shouldn't need a loop.  The -match and replace operators will work on the entire array at once, so you don't need to step through the lines.

Comment: I'm really struggling to get my head around this, it's been a long day! So I have a file containing the original style lines called file.txt, then how does it get written to a new file? When I try to run the lines you said, it just outputs 'False' or 'True'.

Comment: You need to send that output to a new file using out-file or set-content.  I'll update the script.  I don't understand why you're getting the True/False results if you're running that script though. Note: you only need the second $regex = line.  The first was just a starting point for demonstartion.

Comment: Yeah, here's what I'm putting:$regex  = '(OrderLine="\d+" <Image>\d+_outside.jpg</Image>)<Image>\d+_inside.jpg</Image>'
$array = Get-ChildItem $File_Folder\*.xml | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_) -match $regex -replace $regex,'$1' -replace '_outside\.jpg','.pdf' | Set-Content -path $_ }

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14909954/Order_PO11770060001.xml - actual file, in case that's of use

Comment: It's just occurred to me that the match won't work because I chopped some of the original data... doh!

Comment: Do you have enough to get the regex adjusted for the missing data?

Comment: It still just seems to output true or false to the file, I've just got in so I will try to look into it some more.

Answer (score 0):

Success! I couldn't have done it without the help of mjolinor so a thousand thanks for taking the time to help me out, I really do appreciate it.

In the end I bodged it by replacing one then running through and doing the other, I think it was the match statement that was outputting true/false and I didn't have the skills to work round it. This way is not the cleanest but it got the job done:

```
$File_Folder = "C:\PSTEST\TEST\"
$regex  = '<Image>\d+_inside.jpg</Image>'
$array = Get-ChildItem $File_Folder\*.xml | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_) -replace '_outside\.jpg','.pdf' | Set-Content -path $_ }
$array = Get-ChildItem $File_Folder\*.xml | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_) -replace $regex,'' | Set-Content -path $_ }
```